# AWS DynamoDb Python : Filtering or Querying by the Contents of a List in DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am a new to the AWS Lambda using Python runtime , i am writing a python lambda function which gets the result from dynamo db, below is my patient table dynamo db structure .

```
{
"patient_id": 161,
  "patientVisits": [
    {
  "Diagnosis": [
    {
      "Diagnosis_Completion": "Definitive",
      "DiagnosisId": 100,
      "ICD_Code": "test ICd code for dignosis Id 100"
    }
  ],
  "Follow_Up_Recommendation": "Follow up recommendation Test",
  "visitId": 123
},
{
  "Diagnosis": [
    {
      "Diagnosis_Completion": "Definitive",
      "DiagnosisId": 100,
      "ICD_Code": "test ICd code for dignosis Id 100"
    }
  ], 
  "visitId": 124
}]}
```

Here patient table has key as patient_id and its has many attributes , one of the attribute is List of patientVisits which again has visitId and also includes the List of Diagnosis, my requirement is it to get the Diagnosis based on patientId and visitId, so i have tried to write the python lambda is like this

```
def list(event, context):
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['PATIENT_TABLE'])
    patientId = 130
    visitId = 124
    # fetch all patientVisits from the database
    result = table.query(
    ProjectionExpression="#patientId, #pv.Diagnosis",
    FilterExpression = '#pv.visitId = :visit_id',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={ "#patientId": "patientId", "#pv" : "patientVisits"}, # Expression Attribute Names for Projection Expression only.
    ExpressionAttributeValues= {":visit_id": visitId},
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('patient_id').eq(patientId)   
)
```

the above is giving me zero results, Can you please help me on this , if i change ProjectionExpression #pv.Diagnosis to #pv[0].Diagnosis aswell the FilterExpression then this works only gives me  the zeroth index and also if the visitId matches with the zeroth index visitID, but i want to get the Diagnosis list from the patientVisits which is based on the visitId and patientId, can you please help me on this . struggling from the long time

Thanks you in advance!!!

Comment: Can anyone help on this ? stuck on this issue from long back not able to progress further .

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: try changing this: FilterExpression = '#pv.visitId = :visit_id', to FilterExpression =Attr('#pv.visit_id').eq(visitId)

Comment: @dvd86 Not working :(